# How to use Android navigation when getting OAuthToken from website

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am working on converting our app to the latest standards with the latest libraries. Currently, to log in, the user is navigated to a chrome CustomTab. They then log in with their information, and the website redirects back to our login activity which then takes us to whatever view comes after that. Here is how we currently do that:

```
class OAuthCallbackActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        private const val STATE_KEY = "state"
        private const val RESPONSE_TYPE_KEY = "code"
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW == intent.action && intent.data != null) {
            val status = getStatusFromUri()
            Timber.e("The intent from the callback activity was fine")

           if (!intent.data!!.getQueryParameter("code").isNullOrBlank() &&
                    !intent.data!!.getQueryParameter("state").isNullOrBlank()) {
                startActivity(LoginActivity.startIntent(this, intent.data))
            }
        } else {

        }

        finish()
    }

    private fun getStatusFromUri(): String? {
        return intent.data!!.getQueryParameter(STATE_KEY)
    }
}
```

This activity captures the `intent.data` to LoginActivity and starts it. Here is the code for LoginActivity:

```
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: LoginViewModel

    companion object {
        const val CALLBACK_KEY = "LoginActivity.CALLBACK_KEY"

        fun startIntent(context: Context): Intent {
            return Intent(context, LoginActivity::class.java).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        }

        fun startIntent(context: Context, uriData: Uri?): Intent {
            val result = Intent(context, LoginActivity::class.java)
            result.putExtra(CALLBACK_KEY, uriData)
            return result
        }
    }

    override fun layoutResId(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_login
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel::class.java)

        // View Binding was here

        viewModel.checkForUserSession() // checks to see if a user session already exists in storage

        // Observers
        val loadingObserver = Observer<Boolean> { isLoading ->
            when(isLoading) {
                true -> progress_indicator.visibility = VISIBLE
                false -> progress_indicator.visibility = GONE
            }
        }

        val authObserver = Observer<UserSession> { userSession ->
            if(userSession != null)  advanceToEnrollment()
        }

        viewModel.isLoadingRequired.observe(this, loadingObserver)
        viewModel.userSession.observe(this, authObserver)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        viewModel.processNewIntent(getIntent()) // this parses the intent.data that was passed, then grabs the data needed to construct a JWT
    }

    private fun advanceToEnrollment() {
        startActivity(EnrollmentActivity.startIntent(this))
        finish()
    }
}
```

How do i handle this in the Android Navigation single activity architecture? We currently progress to a new activity that hosts multiple fragments.

Thanks for any help!

e:

I would like to fetch the OAuthToken from the uri callback from Chrome (that looks like my_app://oauth) and save it to SharedPreferences, then progress to another fragment. I guess the tldr of my question is how do I process the intent returned from the website containing the oauth token using android navigation without having to start a new activity to listen for that intent callback. Sorry if I wasn’t clear

Comment: I am personally having trouble understanding what your goal is. Are you wanting to setup a Android navigation menu after a successful login? Or are you asking how to get a successful response?

Comment: I would like to fetch the OAuthToken from the uri callback from Chrome (that looks like my_app://oauth) and save it to SharedPreferences, then progress to another fragment. I guess the tldr of my question is how do I process the intent returned from the website containing the oauth token using android navigation without having to start a new activity to listen for that intent callback. Sorry if I wasn’t clear